# How to set multiple default reviewers in BitBucket cloud?

Tags: bitbucket

We are currently migrating from BitBucket server to cloud. And one of the options which we are leveraging in server is that you could set multiple default reviewers per branch. Which meant that I could have separate teams of reviewers being added. So for example if I have a team of leads 1 ... n; I could create 1 ... n default reviewers in bitbucket server. So it would imply that I needed `n` approvals from `n` different teams.

But in cloud this option is not there and all of `n * m (m being variable number of engineers per team)` engineers are added by default which means that all of the `n` required approvals could be coming from one single team which does not work for me.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Well it is as you said. Server has way more control over things like this. You could create your own bot that would do the same thing, but don't think there is any control like this built-in

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no out-of-the-box option in Bitbucket cloud to add reviewer groups to pull requests, not on repository nor branch level.

We felt the pain and built [Workzone](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211303/workzone-pullrequest-workflow?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) for Bitbucket where you can add reviewer groups/teams at branch or even file/module level, and enforce an approval quota per group before the PR can be merged.

For your use case you would define `n` Workzone rules, one for each group/team and set the quota to `1`.

[image: Workzone reviewer group rules]